# UICollectionViewCell flip animation does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to implement a flip animation on an UICollectionViewCell. The following code doesn't work (no animation at all), so I'm asking for help.

My custom cell has a content view, containing two UIViews (FrontsideView and BacksideView). Inside them I have a few labels with constraints.

[image]

The code should be executed when tapping on the cell (delegates work fine). This is my custom cell:

```swift
class ProjectCVCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var frontsideView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var backsideView: UIView!
    
    func flipAnimation() {
        let transitionOptions: UIView.AnimationOptions = [.transitionFlipFromRight]
        UIView.transition(with: self.contentView, duration: 0.5, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
            self.frontsideView.isHidden = !self.frontsideView.isHidden
            self.backsideView.isHidden = !self.backsideView.isHidden
        }, completion: {
            finished in
        } )
    }
}
```

And this is the didSelectItemAt function:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? ProjectCVCell else { return }
        cell.flipAnimation()
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should need to use ```collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? ProjectCVCell else { return }``` inside the didSelect.

Comment: `dequeueReusableCell` you don't allow to call this method outside `cellForItemAt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
UIView.transition(with: self.contentView, duration: 0.5, options: transitionOptions, animations: {
        self.frontsideView.alpha = self.frontsideView.alpha == 1.0 ? 0.0 : 1.0
        self.backsideView.alpha = self.backsideView.alpha == 1.0 ? 0.0 : 1.0
}, completion: { _ in
} )
```

And change

```
guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at:indexPath) as? ProjectCVCell else { return }
```

Comment: The last one did the trick. But it is cellForItem, because it is a collectionView as @Raja-Kishan mentioned.